# How to know if a Qt form valid

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow, qtcore

I currently have a Qt form class called `foo' derived from QMainWindow.

Now in some other class I have something like this

```
class someclass
{
   private:
      foo* form;
   ......
   public:
      someclass()
      {
          form = NULL; 
      }    
};
```

Now there is a method in someclass that needs to know if foo* is valid if it is pointing
to a valid foo form. I wanted to know what was the best way of achieving this. Should I go with

```
if(form!=NULL) {...}
```

The problem is that the above method does not gurantee a reliable valid form . Any suggestions ?

Comment: @Charles: please do not remove any tags that are closely relevant to the topic. You do not only needlessly bump the question, but you also remove the Q/A from a category to which it is relevant.

Comment: @Laszlo, I was about to smack you down with a plethora of Meta links that demonstrate that you shouldn't add library tags to questions to which the tag would apply only to an answer, but I apparently completely misremembered previous community consensus.  I apologize for the inconvenience my righteous tag burnination caused.

Comment: @Charles: No worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for smart pointers. Usually, this check is done by a weak pointer. This would not hold the ownership for the object, but it could check for the validity with the [isNull() method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qweakpointer.html#isNull).

Qt has a convenient class established for this, called [QWeakPointer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qweakpointer.html). It is usually used in pair with shared pointers, which would be [QSharedPointer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html) in the Qt world.

> The QWeakPointer class holds a weak reference to a shared pointer
>
> The QWeakPointer is an automatic weak reference to a pointer in C++. It cannot be used to dereference the pointer directly, but it can be used to verify if the pointer has been deleted or not in another context.
>
> QWeakPointer objects can only be created by assignment from a QSharedPointer.

Here goes the method you could actually use to see if the main QSharedPointer owning the object has deleted the referenced pointer.

> bool QWeakPointer::isNull() const
>
> Returns true if this object is holding a reference to a null pointer.
>
> Note that, due to the nature of weak references, the pointer that QWeakPointer references can become null at any moment, so the value returned from this function can change from false to true from one call to the next.

This way, the other class would not need to get a reference to the pointer with ownership, but depending on your exact use case, you could just go for QSharedPointer everywhere.

Comment: sharedptrs don't work nicely with QObject when passing a parent (which you should always do for dialogs, to not break window stacking), as both the parent and the sharedptr take ownership and the sharedptr will cause double-deletion in case the parent deletes first. So I'd be careful with statements such as "you could just go for QSharedPointer everywhere.", in a Qt context.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: hmm, it seems the intended meaning of "Everywhere" was not coming through for you in that sentence. :) It is trying to refer to every place such as: the class which has the shared pointer member and any outter code getting access to that. The word is not referring to "each scenario". Fwiw, I even wrote that "depending on your use case" which means not in each scenario. Feel free to propose a suggested edit if you think you can make it clearer, but I think the intention still stands correct unless there are any other issues.

Comment: As for the parent/child relationhip, I am not sure that is the right way ultimately and all the time if you wish to make sure that a pointer is valid. I personally believe that information is not relevant to the OP's intention. Perhaps, the OP was just trying to provide as much information as possible, but either way, I do not see the ultimate problem with a parentless mainwindow personally. If it was like that, the API would probably prohibit it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use QScopedPointer or QSharedPointer depending on the scope of foo class instead of foo*. That would allow reliably check if pointer is valid, comparing pointer to null won't help to detect deleted pointer pointing into the wild.